# Is saying 'necessary information' wrong English?

Tags: expressions

I wrote the sentence that 'people don't get necessary information'.
But an editor changed 'people don't get information they need'.

Whole sentence is
'People don't get necessary information at the time of a natural disaster
such as earth quakes.'

Comment: The second one is more direct regarding the *need*, but both are OK grammar-wise. More context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As a stand-alone sentence, both of these sound fine. Perhaps in context it sounded worse, or maybe nothing was wrong at all -- maybe your editor just prefers the sound of one sentence to the other.